# how to pass custom design image to Shopify cart

Tags: jquery, image, shopify, cart

Basically I have a customizer where user can customize their product and after customization I am able to capture that design as image but I don't know to pass that image to cart show that image as product image.

For the purpose I take a product that has no image, I do this just for the purpose to show my custom image instead of the product image.

Anyone have idea please help.
Here is my working link

> [Bottle Customizer](https://shop.mycleanpath.com/collections/all)
>   (store password: thazia)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to save the image and upload it to Shopify files then you can pass the image URL to a custom hidden field with some kind of property.

So for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="properties[custom-image]" value="IMAGE URL HERE" />
```

Then in the cart template you will have to loop the `line_item` properties until you find this `custom-image` property and use that one instead of the `line_item.image` object.

This will be true if you have a way to save the image in a way that you can link to it afterwards.